# Oracle SQL Query Tuning for non indexed table

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

i have two tables

```
TABLE_1
TABLE_2
```

TABLE_2 act as a reference table and doesn't have any index on this table.

I framed one query but it taking more than 12hours to get the data,
it is possible to reframe below query ?

```
SELECT column1, column2
  FROM table_1
 WHERE     TRIM (column1) IS NOT NULL
       AND TRIM (column2) IS NULL
       AND date = (SELECT MAX (date) FROM table_1)
       AND NOT EXISTS
              (SELECT 1
                 FROM table_2
                WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE (TRIM (UPPER (column1)), '[^a-zA-Z0-9]') LIKE
                         (   '%'
                          || REGEXP_REPLACE (TRIM (UPPER (code)),
                                             '[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
                          || '%'));
```

Comment: Syntax error at "WHERE  where", etc.

Comment: Great. Next one is "AND TRIM(COLUMN2) IS NULL DATE=". Missing AND perhaps?

Comment: @jarlh good catch updated

Comment: And `DATE` is a reserved word. Needs to be delimited as `"DATE"`.

Comment: @jarlh thats fine let it be. could you please help me to reframe to alternative method. I'm tired of trying this since last 4 days and only way is to create temp table by using CTAS method and have to run the query, this is the solution i found online, but just checking any alternative method reframing my query

Comment: The EXISTS subquery isn't correlated - by purpose? Or is it? Which tables do column1 and code belong to?

Comment: It is, @jarlh - on `table1.column1 LIKE table2.code` (with additions of regular expressions etc.)

Comment: yes Table_1 has key column i need to filter that by matching column1 & code

Comment: How large are those tables, @Cyber? Regular expressions will be (very) slow on large tables ...

Comment: @Littlefoot Not so much table_1 has 52257 
table 2 has 114273

Comment: And how many rows in table_1 have date=(select max(date) from table_1)? Can you post the execution plan? If there are very few rows with that condition, there may be a way to optimize it.

Comment: `LIKE '%whatever'` and regexes are notorious performance killers in WHERE clauses. If you were to [edit] your question to show us some sample data, we might be able to help you refactor the query to make it faster. Also please show your complete table DDL.

Comment: also run an explain plan and post that

Comment: What is the purpose of the TRIM in "TRIM (column1) IS NOT NULL AND TRIM (column2) IS NULL"?   If the column is null, it will be null whether you trim it or not.

Comment: The optimiser knows the number of rows where column1 is not null (assuming the statistics are up to date - are they?) but it doesn't know the number of rows where trim(column1) is not null. It will most likely guess at 5%. That kind of thing can mess up subsequent estimates and affect join orders and access methods.